# VS 2010 Keeps Adding File Back After Deletion

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I can delete a file from my solution explorer, and commit the changes back to TFS. But when I exit VS it adds the file back. So when I return it shows up as a pending add. How do I get rid of it!

Thanks

Comment: What sort of file is it?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Team Explorer view (View --> Team Explorer). Double click on Source Control of the team project you are working on. You can then select the source tree of your project and right click, then select *Undo Pending Changes* to remove the pending add of the file.